# How to change application deployment path in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have this directory structure in Tomcat: /webapps/webserver/warfile

When I try to start Tomcat, it can't look to the subfolder webserver and thus read the WarFile. If I change the directory structure like this: /webapps/warfile, everything works fine and I can access my application.

I know it would be easier if I just move the war file to the webapps directory, but it is a long story why I need in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try changing base directory for deployment

Find `server.xml` at `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`

Then, change appBase to your required path.

Please refer [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html)